# Cannot convert value of type 'TupleView<(Text, Text)>' to closure result type 'Text'

Tags: swift, swiftui, viewbuilder

I am trying to understand why I keep getting an error when I try to use this custom layout view
I've created.

Here is the error (also commented in the code below):

```
Cannot convert value of type 'TupleView<(Text, Text)>' to closure result type 'Text'
```

And here is the code that generates the problem.

```swift
struct BaseRecordView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {

        // Error: Cannot convert value of type 'TupleView<(Text, Text)>' 
        // to closure result type 'Text'
        BaseRecordView() { 
            Text("125.6")
            Text("kg")
        } subHeading: {
            Text("44.1 BMI")
        } content: {
            Text("Something here")
        }

    }
}
```

and this is how I have defined `BaseRecordView`:

```swift
struct BaseRecordView<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var heading: Content
    @ViewBuilder var subHeading: Content
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content
    
    init(
         @ViewBuilder heading: @escaping () -> Content,
         @ViewBuilder subHeading: @escaping () -> Content,
         @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content)
    {
        self.heading = heading()
        self.subHeading = subHeading()
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        // layout content here
        heading
        subHeading
        content
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? What is the meaning of `TupleView<(Text, Text)>` in this context?

Comment: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402841/swiftui-view-with-multiple-viewbuilder) can be useful for you too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you declared your `BaseRecordView` with all 3 of its generic `View` properties having the same `Content` type, but you are passing a different type of view to `heading` that to `subHeading` and `content`.

If you want to be able to pass 3 different types of Views, you need 3 different generic type parameters.

```
struct BaseRecordView<Heading: View, Subheading: View, Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder private let heading: Heading
    @ViewBuilder private let subHeading: Subheading
    @ViewBuilder private let content: Content

    init(
         @ViewBuilder heading: @escaping () -> Heading,
         @ViewBuilder subHeading: @escaping () -> Subheading,
         @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content)
    {
        self.heading = heading()
        self.subHeading = subHeading()
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        // layout content here
        heading
        subHeading
        content
    }
}

struct BaseRecordView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {

        // Error: Cannot convert value of type 'TupleView<(Text, Text)>'
        // to closure result type 'Text'
        BaseRecordView() {
            Text("125.6")
            Text("kg")
        } subHeading: {
            Text("44.1 BMI")
        } content: {
            Text("Something here")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you!  That makes a lot of sense now.